# Git Sponsor access

Tags: github

I sighed up to be a sponsor today.  10.00 tier.  I have been a user for sometime and finally bit the bullet and became a sponsor.  I did the 10.00 tier to get early access.  But it's been hours and I still get get access to the sponsor release.  Could not find an easy way to contact someone about it.  So, here I am.  Can someone please assist?

Donald

Comment: ... can't get access.  not "... still get get..." sigh.. been a long day.

Comment: Are you a "private" sponsor? Reading this, I think your sponsorship has to be marked as public for it to work: https://github.com/elementary/builds/issues/28

If you're still having issues after that, I'd recommend opening a new issue on the linked github page. It's more likely to get attention than this.